# Display the selected portion of the image

Tags: android, android-canvas, ontouchlistener

I am implementing scroll and crop functionality.
Have attached a screenshot for reference.

What I am trying to achieve is:

1. When a user drags her finger on the bigger image, I need to zoom the selected area.
2. I need to place a rectangular box indicating the area that is selected.
3. User should be able to change the size of this box by entering different values in an editText.
4. On confirmation I want to crop and send the selected area to my server.

****Problem that I am facing:****

1. I am not able to place this rectangular box on the selected area.
2. I need help understanding how can I change size of this rectangular box when values in an EditText changes.
3. When I drag on the bigger image, I am able to zoom only for the one third of th image on the left. The other two third does not zoom out.

[image]

This is my OnTouchListener in Activity

```
  mural.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

            int topParam = mural.getPaddingTop();
            int rightParam = mural.getPaddingRight();
            int maxTopParam = topParam + mural.getMaxHeight();
            int maxRightParam = rightParam + mural.getMaxWidth();

            int x = 0, y = 0;

            Matrix m = new Matrix();
            if (event.getX() > topParam && event.getX() < maxTopParam) {
                x = (int) event.getX();

            }

            if (event.getY() > maxRightParam && event.getY() < rightParam) {
                y = (int) event.getY();

            }
            mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) mural.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, x, y, 80, 80, m, true);
            croped.setImageBitmap(croppedBitmap);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

This is my XML file

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.outlineindia.zooming_drag_touch_crop_portion_image_examaple.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/cropedmg"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ImageView

        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/mural"
        android:src="@drawable/muraltheme"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```